# .Net versions used to compile visual studio projects are different, which one is used at run-time?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, visual-studio-2013, clr

I have a ASP.Net MVC project in visual studio and C# class library project.
C# class library project is referenced in my MVC project.

E.g. if i have compiled C# class library project with .Net 2.0 framework and MVC project with .Net 4.0 Framework.

When IIS worker process executes the code from referenced C# class library What version of .net framework is used ? is it .net framework 2.0 or 4.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

It will be the latest version of assembly available.

Your IIS only looks at the bin folder of your mvc project and all the dlls in it. Since your mvc project references a later version of .net, that's the version that will be put in its bin folder.

Comment: Thanks. it make sense for the DLLs that are copied to bin directory. When it's references the library in GAC then what it does?